# Concatenate a layer to itself

Tags: python, keras, layer, categorical-data

I am learning to work with categorical data following the code examples of same [old entity embedding by Abhishek Thakur](https://www.kaggle.com/abhishek/same-old-entity-embeddings). He is using visual studio one as the python editor, but I am using Google Colab notebook. The code is the same, but I am getting error on a concatenation.
According to the tensor documentation:

```
layers.Concatenate(axis = along which to concatenate)
```

The sample code uses:

```
x=layers.Concatenate()(outputs)
```

without mentioning the axis to which the concatenation is supposed to happen. Using the code as it is, I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
       <ipython-input-15-8d7152b44077> in <module>()
       ----> 1 run(0)

        5 frames
        /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/merge.py in        build(self, input_shape)
491     # Used purely for shape validation.
492     if not isinstance(input_shape[0], tuple) or len(input_shape) < 2:
--> 493       raise ValueError('A `Concatenate` layer should be called '
494                        'on a list of at least 2 inputs')
495     if all(shape is None for shape in input_shape):

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer should be called on a list of at least 2 inputs
```

I get the same error even when I add the argument axis = 1.

Here is my sample code:

```
import os
import gc
import joblib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics, preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import Model 
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from tensorflow.keras import callbacks
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import utils

def create_model(data, catcols):
  #init lit of inputs for embedding
  inputs = []

  #init list of outputs for embeddings
  outputs = []

  #loop over all categorical colums

  for c in catcols:
      #find the number of unique values in the column
      num_unique_values = int(data[c].nunique())
      #simple dimension of embedding calculator
      #min size is half of the number of unique values
      #max size is 50. max size depends on the number of unique
      #categories too. 
      embed_dim = int(min(np.ceil((num_unique_values)/2), 50))

      #simple keras input layer with size 1
      inp = layers.Input(shape=(1, ))

      #add embedding layer to raw input 
      #embedding size is always 1 more than uique values in input 
      out = layers.Embedding(num_unique_values + 1, embed_dim, name = c)(inp)

      #1-d spatial dropout is the standard for embedding layers 
      #you can use it in NLP tasks too 
      out = layers.SpatialDropout1D(0.3)(out)

      #reshape the input to the dimension of embedding
      #this becomes our output layer for current feature
      out = layers.Reshape(target_shape=(embed_dim, ))(out)

      #add input to input list
      inputs.append(inp)

      #add out to output list
      outputs.append(out)

      #concatenate all output layers
      x = layers.Concatenate(axis=1)(outputs)

      #add a batchnorm layer
      x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

      #add layers with dropout
      x= layers.Dense(300, acivation="relu")(x)
      x= layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
      x= layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

      x = layers.Dense(300, activation="relu")(x)
      x = layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
      x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

      y = layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)

      #create final model
      model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=y)

      model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
      
      return model_selection



from sklearn import metrics, preprocessing
def run(fold):
  df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/train_folds.csv')

  features = [f for f in df.columns if f not in ("id", "target", "kfold")]

  for col in features:
    df.loc[:, col] = df[col].astype(str).fillna("NONE") #fill the nan values with nan. The function "fillna" was created to fill only one column;
                                                      # at a time it is not tested against a list of columns. 
    for feat in features:
      lbl_enc = preprocessing.LabelEncoder() #create the label encoder
      df.loc[:, feat] = lbl_enc.fit_transform(df[feat].values) #label encode all columns

     #split the data
     df_train = df[df.kfold != fold].reset_index(drop=True) #get the training data. Remember that we created a column name kfold. if kfold = fold,
                                                        #then we train all the other folds but the argument fold. 

     df_valid = df[df.kfold == fold].reset_index(drop=True) #get the validation data. The argument fold is reserved for validation

     #create the model
    model = create_model(df, features)

    #our features are lists of lists
    xtrain = [df_train[features].values[:, k] for k in range(len(features))]

    xvalid = [df_valid[features].values[:, k] for k in range(len(features))]

    #retrieve target values
    ytain = df_train.target.values
    yvalid = df_valid.target.values

    #convert target columsn to categories 
    #binarization
    ytrain_cat = utils.to_categorical(ytrain)
    yvalid_cat = utils.to_categorical(yvalid)

    #fit the model
    model.fit(xtrain, ytrain_cat, validation_data=(xvalid, yvalid_cat), verbose=1, batch_size=1024, epochs=3)

    #generation validation predictions
    valid_preds = model.predict(xvalid)[:, 1]

    #metrics
    print(metrics.roc_auc_score(yvalid, valid_preds))

    #save memory space by clearing session
    K.clear_session()
```

I ran the code:

```
run(0)
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the axis, you seem to be giving a list of only one input to concatenate, where at least two inputs are expected. We cannot say more than that without you sharing your code around the error.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy. I just added my code. Regarding layers.Concatenate, it does not require 2 inputs, but layers.concatenate (lowercase c) does according to the Keras documentation.

Comment: It does, just look at your error, that the docs do not mention it does not mean its not there

Comment: Seems the problem is the indentation of your code, as you put the concatenate layer inside the for loop, and it should be outside

Comment: ‍♂️ you are right. Thanks @Dr.Snoopy.